# Beginning C program freezing at scanf

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with scanf freezing. I've looked around and while some questions are similar, they haven't helped in solving my problem.

```
main(int argc, char **argv) {
//FILE *stream = stdin;
if (stdin == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open file");
    return 0;
}
int exists = 0;
char letter;
char next = 'H';
char word[30];
int frequency = -1;
int sample = -1;
char  *channels;
channels=malloc(sizeof(7*sizeof(char)));
int bitres = -1;
int secondE = 0;


while (exists == 0) {
    scanf("%c", &letter);   //this is the problem, possibly scanf
    printf("AFTER");
    if (letter == EOF) {
    //  printf(letter);
        printf("HEADER NOT DETECTED");
        return 0;
    }
```

I've pinpointed the problem using printf. I'm currently piping in another file through command prompt into this program. When I reach scanf it just hangs. If anyone knows the solution I would be very thankful.

On a side note, is using scanf bad practice? It's just as easy to assign stdin to a file pointer (I actually have this commented out) but scanf  seemed just as easy.

Comment: Must you use `scanf()`? It's often hard to use, especially for beginners. Have you tried `fgetc()` instead? Also, `scanf()` never returns an `EOF` value in that way (`fgetc()` does).

Comment: what do u mean by it hangs ..? you continously press any key and nothing happen or prntf("AFTER") is printing continously..?

Comment: It never reaches "AFTER." However if I place a printf statement right before scanf the statement will print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by freezing. i run this code. when your code reach in `scanf` it wait for your input. you give some input , then see what happen.

*scanf is not a bad practice* .

```
channels=(char*)malloc(sizeof(7*sizeof(char)));
int bitres = -1;
int secondE = 0;


while (exists == 0) 
{
    scanf("%c", &letter);   // ok
    printf("AFTER");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c", letter);
    printf("\n");
    if (letter == EOF) {
    //  printf(letter);
     printf("HEADER NOT DETECTED"); }
    return 0;
}
```

scanf never return EOF also.

Comment: I'm piping in a file that has text in it. Piping will result in the file being stdin, no? If so, scanf should be reading the first character of stdin (the first character of the text within my file I've piped in).

Comment: what do you mean by piping? if you give the file name as command line parameter then its not threat like a file in stdin. its just a simple parameter.

Comment: I'm using commandline. My input looks like this: filetobepipe | programimshowingyouonstackoverflow

Comment: for command line parameter passing you can see [http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html]

Comment: No. I'm not using commandline like that. I'm piping another file in. I don't know how else to explain it, I'm new to C.

Comment: filetobepipe | program does not pipe a file.  You need a program which sends the file to its stdout like cat.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do. I left cat out in my comment.

Comment: I've only been programming in C for a bit over a quarter of a century, and I find `scanf()` too hard to use reliably, so I don't.  I'll use `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to parse them; that is a lot easier to get right, in my experience (and makes error reporting a lot easier too!).  You should always check that `scanf()` returns the number of values you expected it to convert; it can return -1 if it encounters EOF.  It can return 0 if there is data but it doesn't match the format (for example, the next character is a letter but you're trying to scan a number).

Comment: I appreciate your response Jonathan. I decided to try and use fgetc(), it is still not working at that exact location. It must be some problem with the file I'm inputting

Comment: @BananaHammock: Also, if you use `fgetc()`, don't forget to change the type of `letter` to `int`. The `EOF` value is a special integer value that *cannot* be held in a `char` type, and this will be messing up your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However I am still having the same problems. Extremely frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

```
while (exists == 0) 
{
    scanf("%c", &letter);   // ok
    printf("AFTER");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c", letter);
    printf("\n");
    if (letter == EOF) {
    //  printf(letter);
     printf("HEADER NOT DETECTED"); }
    return 0;
}
```

So when using this the

```
if (letter == E0F)
```

section above is a bit too literal. Why not just use a *char* to store your desired answer and use the following to create

```
if(strcmp(letter, *desired char here*) == 0){
```

just a guess considering the fact it may be client side if your scanf function is freezing only in debug but with the example above it is a bit more user friendly when reading the code and will not have any errors when dealing with other characters and integers later on in your program. Depending on what you want to accomplish with it.